# Google BigQuery: Unstable tabledata: list behaviour when using startIndex

Tags: google-bigquery

When we need to fetch whole table data from BQ, it's easy to do it with tabledata: list - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/list .
We use startIndex and maxResults for pagination.

The problem is that sometimes startIndex stops working and we get data always from row 0 to  maxResults. After several hours it works again.

We found out that it happens 3-5 hours after table creation and/or streaming inserts in it.
First hours everything is ok, then startIndex not working, than ok again.

Comment: Can you share your project_id and a few timestamps for when you observed these incorrect responses?

Comment: Michael, just now (22.11.2014 22:56 UTC+3) GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/docdoc-01/datasets/****/tables/requests_d*****_11_2014/data?maxResults=1&startIndex=100 or 1 - the same row returned.

Comment: @MichaelSheldon, any news so far?

Answer (score 1):

For a more robust solution, prefer using "pageToken" instead of paginating with "startIndex".

Comment: Felipe, pageToken did not work in my scenario as well.

Comment: you are right - 'list' is not a job, so it doesn't have a jobid